# folium geojson multiple layers control

Tags: python, loops, maps, layer, folium

I'm trying to create a map that has multiple layers output from the key value pairs of a geojson, I can create the map and the layers but the layer filter doesn't work.

data = {"type": "FeatureCollection", "name": "OVE", "crs": {"type": "name", "properties": {"name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84"}}, "features": [{"type": "Feature", "geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [-75.849254, 47.643435]}, "properties": {"id": 1, "Country": "Canada", "Category": "hot dogs", "Designac": null}}, {"type": "Feature", "geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [-75.840219, 47.971115]}, "properties": {"id": 2, "Country": "Canada", "Category": "hamburger", "Designac": null}}, {"type": "Feature", "geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [-75.849254, 48.278694]}, "properties": {"id": 3, "Country": "Canada", "Category": "barbecue", "Designac": null}}, {"type": "Feature", "geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [-74.792153, 48.284706]}, "properties": {"id": 6, "Country": "Canada", "Category": "hot dogs", "Designac": null}}, {"type": "Feature", "geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [-75.298115, 47.643435]}, "properties": {"id": 7, "Country": "Canada", "Category": "barbecue", "Designac": null}}, {"type": "Feature", "geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [-75.298115, 47.971115]}, "properties": {"id": 8, "Country": "Canada", "Category": "barbecue", "Designac": null}}, {"type": "Feature", "geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [-75.28908, 48.284706]}, "properties": {"id": 9, "Country": "Canada", "Category": "hamburger", "Designac": null}}]}

my code is this:

```
data_geo= folium.GeoJson(data)
Category = []
for i in data["features"]:
    Category.append(i["properties"]["Category"])

set_res = set(Category) 
list_category = list(set_res)
for i in range(len(list_category)):
    if list_category[i] == None:
        list_category[i] = 'No Value'

list_category_lower = [name.lower() for name in list_category]
list_category_lower = sorted(list_category_lower)
l_replace = [s.replace(' ', '') for s in list_category_lower]

for feature in data_geo.data['features']:
    for replace, lower in zip(l_replace, list_category_lower):    
        globals()['%s' % replace] = folium.FeatureGroup(lower)
        category = feature['properties']['Category']
        if category == None:
            category = 'No Value'
        category = category.lower()
    
        if feature['properties']['Country'] == 'Canada':            
            for i in list_category_lower:
                if category == i:                   
                    folium.Marker(location=list(reversed(feature['geometry']['coordinates'])),
                        icon=folium.Icon(color="green",icon='info-sign'),                                  
                        popup="<b>Timberline Lodge</b>",
                        tooltip = feature['properties']['Category'],                        
                    ).add_to(globals()['%s' % replace])
        (globals()['%s' % replace]).add_to(m)  

folium.LayerControl().add_to(m)        
m.save('demo.html')
m
```

[image]

I deselect hamburger but the layer is still displayed

Answer (score 1):

I solved it adding one more conditional

```
for replace, lower in zip(l_replace, list_category_lower):    
    globals()['%s' % replace] = folium.FeatureGroup(lower)
    variable = globals()['%s' % replace]
    #temp = variable.layer_name
    for feature in data_geo.data['features']:

        category = feature['properties']['Category']

        if category == None:
            category = 'No Value'
        category = category.lower()

        if feature['properties']['Country'] == 'Canada':            
            for i in list_category_lower:
                if i == variable.layer_name:
                    if category == i:                        
                        folium.Marker(location=list(reversed(feature['geometry']['coordinates'])),
                            icon=folium.Icon(color="green",icon='info-sign'),                                  
                            popup="<b>Timberline Lodge</b>",
                            tooltip = feature['properties']['Category'],
                            #Categoria=feature['properties']['entidad']
                        ).add_to(variable)
        (globals()['%s' % replace]).add_to(m)  

folium.LayerControl().add_to(m)        
m.save('demo.html')

m
```